# Configure Azure static website to not require a trailing slash

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Storage Account configured as a static website. The static website contains a sub-directory called 'versions', which then contains several other versions of the website. I can display these versions, but it requires a trailing slash, which obviously isn't ideal as most people don't use them.

For example, say the URL of my static websits is https://mystorageaccount.z8.web.core.windows.net...

- No trailing slash - a blank page is displayed (https://mystorageaccount.z8.web.core.windows.net/versions/1.2.3)
- With a trailing slash - the website is displayed as expected (https://mystorageaccount.z8.web.core.windows.net/versions/1.2.3/)

I'm assuming this is because the static website is attempting to serve https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/%24web/versions/1.2.3index.html, but is there a way I can configure the static website to not require the trailing slash?

I did try to specify `/index.html` as the index document, but the static website configuration disallows that.

> If specified, index document name must be between 3 and 255 characters in length, and must not contain any '/' characters.

Comment: is this a single page app (build with react or something similar)?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Yes it is.

Comment: have you seen this?
[link](https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn/)
if you would like https://yourblog.azureedge.net/myawesomepost (without a trailing slash) to resolve to https://yourblog.azureedge.net/myawesomepost.html, you can set the second destination pattern to $1.html$2. The destination pattern in step 8 resolves the asset to https://yourblog.azureedge.net/myawesomepost/index.html. Of course, this means any resource without an extension will resolve to .html.

Comment: @Ron Thanks, but I think that is a bit out of date. It looks like it was written before static websites were added as a feature. Also, we're not using Azure CDN to front the static website, but rather Azure Front Door (which doesn't seem to offer the way of appending the trailing slash when rewriting URL's).

Comment: To me seems that this is an issue with your SPA rather then azure storage blobs. Take a look if there's a way to set pushState to true

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue a couple days ago and found this very old post unanswered so here are my 5 cents.

This is due to an error in Azure static web apps, wether they are inside a blob storage or in the not so shiny new static web apps services. That's why it was not relevant using or not the CDN services.

The problem in short words is that Azure static web apps dosn't add the trailing slash at the end of the url and this makes it impossible to link correctly the resources of the page (scripts, images, fonts, styles, anything), because it ends up looking folder in the parent folder.

The issue is explained here https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/42

**WORKAROUND**

Make sure you add the trailing slash on any link or

Use absolute URLs instead of relative ones.

Comment: That is for static web apps, not static websites in Blob Storage.